# Is there a way to use the choices of a rmarkdown parameter as a vector inside the report?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a rmarkdown report, and below is the header

```
title: ""
author: ""
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  html_document:
    keep_md: yes
    theme: united
    df_print: kable
editor_options: 
  markdown: 
    wrap: 72
params:
  TP:
    label: "Time Point"
    input: select
    choices: [3, 10, 22]
  Integrated:
    label: "Integrated"
    value: TRUE
```

Inside the report, I need to extract the choices of the `params$TP` as a vector as follows.

```r
if (params$Integrated == FALSE){
    data=read.csv(paste0("DataATTimePoint", params$TP, ".csv")) } else {
    data=lapply(params$TP$choices, function(x) read.csv(paste0("DataATTimePoint", x,".csv")))
    data=do.call("rbind",data}
```

But it’s not the right way because (writing `params$TP$choices` is not correct). What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are after is knitting with multiple parameters, and do something based on the values selected. The following will access and print the parameters selected, if the document is *Integrated*. The key is to add `multiple: yes` in the YAML header, and to give a default value in the `value` field.

To get all the choices, `knitr::knit_params` is the helper function that reads YAML headers. It takes a text input of the document to be converted, in this case, if within an interactive environment, can be obtained via `rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()`.

````
---
title: ""
output: html_document
params:
  TP:
    label: "Time Point"
    input: select
    multiple: yes
    choices: [3, 10, 22]
    value: [3, 10]
  Integrated:
    label: "Integrated"
    value: TRUE
---

```{r}
if(params$Integrated) {
    params$TP
}
```
Grab all possible choices from within the document
```{r}
knitr::knit_params(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$contents)$TP$choices
```
````

[image]

Comment: This helps me a lot. I needed to grab all possible choices from within the document, so using the following commands as you suggest help me resolve the problem: knitr::knit_params(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$contents)$TP$choices